# UILabel doesn't fully resize using Auto Layout

Tags: ios, autolayout, uilabel

I meet a strange issue using Auto Layout with a UILabel where it resizes almost to its content size less one line (driving me nuts) in iphone 4s/5/5s (It works fine on the 6/6+)

this is my storyboard setting, I have set the preferred width with explicit

[image]

and I try to add the code in `UITableViewCell` class

```
self.describe.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.describe.frame.size.width
```

But the issue still exist

this is my issue

[image]

**EDIT**

This is my to get height

```
self.address.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = CGRectGetWidth(self.address.bounds)
self.describe.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = CGRectGetWidth(self.describe.bounds)

self.address.text = data.address == nil ? "no data" : data.address
self.describe.text = data.describe == nil ? "no data" : data.describe

self.layoutIfNeeded()
self.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()

return self.contentView.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize).height
```

Label called "Address" in storyboard (you can find it in first image in this question) work fine

Comment: Describe label, number of Lines are setted to 0?

Comment: @JavierFloresFont  of course

Comment: What code are you using to set the height of the cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this it may help you

YourCell.m

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [self.contentView updateConstraintsIfNeeded];
    [super layoutSubviews];
    [self.contentView layoutIfNeeded];
    CGFloat width = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width - 60;//your desire width
    self.yourLAbel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = width;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Please follow this link it may help you

[Dynamic Cells](http://www.fantageek.com/1468/ios-dynamic-table-view-cells-with-varying-row-height-and-autolayout/)

Or try

yourCell.m in awakefromnib method

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    [self setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
    [self updateConstraintsIfNeeded];
}
```

**Edit - 2**

What is your line break mode, it should be

[image]

**Edit:3**

If you are using height constraints for UILable so that you should provide “Greater than or equal" relation for height autoLayout modify the height for you.

[image: Relation Height]

Comment: issue still exist,Thank you for your answer

Comment: @jansma are you using Height constraints for UILabel?

Comment: Yes ,I have tried, I set the height constraint with 14 and give 250 priority to it @Vishu

Comment: @jansma not modify priority. I mean to say relation. I provided image description in my answer. Please see it.

Comment: Same as before  @Vishu

Comment: I think I might have solved this ,`translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoContraints`is set to `false` for the `contentView` @Vishu

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your problem correctly, then you don't have any issue with auto layout. You can tell your label to consume your desired width and height with auto layout. However you may wanna check how many lines you are allowing in your label.

[image]

If you look into the size inspector in your storyboard, you can specify as many lines as you want to show by specifying the number in the Lines field. If it is "0" then that means that your Label can take all the contents, but then you may have a trouble if you have set a size for your label. So, some contents will be truncated. Now, you can either set the "Lines" field in the attribute inspector to zero and set a width and height or you can specify the number of lines that it should allow and again set the size with auto layout.